# Java String split() loses string

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String called `raw`.  I am trying to split it into an array like so:

`lines = raw.split("\\r?\\n|\\r");`

This works well for the first few occurrences but then it breaks and totally loses the rest of the string.  E.g. raw is `This is my string\n\nThis is a new paragraph\nThis is another line` and becomes `{"This is my string", "", "This is a new paragraph"}`.  Is this a bug within Java or am I doing something wrong?  How can I fix it?

Edit: I do want to keep blank lines.  `[\\n\\r]+` does not keep blank lines

Comment: With your input and your `split`, I get 4 items, as expected: `{"This is my string", "", "This is a new paragraph", "This is another line"}`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use regex:

```
raw.split("[\\r\\n]+");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't fix my problem, the string is still being lost and I do want to keep blank lines.

Comment: please, post more string (not 3 rows) and expected output

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as expected:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String raw = "This is my string\n\nThis is a new paragraph\nThis is another line";
        String[] lines = raw.split("\\r?\\n|\\r");
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
This is my string

This is a new paragraph
This is another line
```

It is therefore likely that the problem is with how you examine/display the result of `split()`, not with the `split()` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could clean up that regex liek this:

```
[\\n\\r]+
```

the + means it will look for whitespace as far as it can before splitting

chances are there's a big in how you're trying to view the answer or something else, I could help you more if you show some code.

if you want to **keep the spaces**, try

```
(?=[\\n\\r]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "multi line" flag and simply split on end-of-line:

```
lines = raw.split("(?m)$\\s*");
```

The term `\s*` consumes the newline characters.

---

Here's some test code:

```
String raw  = "This is my string\n\nThis is a new paragraph\nThis is another line";
String[] lines = raw.split("(?m)$\\s*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString( lines));
```

Output:

```
[This is my string, This is a new paragraph, This is another line]
```